# subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm trying to install the package: libhdf5-serial-dev using the following terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev
```

This gives me the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed
   libhdf5-serial-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,126 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 186283 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libhdf5-serial-dev (from .../libhdf5-serial-dev_1.8.4-patch1-3ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libhdf5-serial-dev_1.8.4-patch1-3ubuntu2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/hdf5.h', which is also in package hdf5 1.8.12-2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libhdf5-serial-dev_1.8.4-patch1-3ubuntu2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

A similar post on askubuntu was fixed using a command of the form:

```
sudo dpkg -r libhdf5-serial-dev_1.8.4-patch1-3ubuntu2_i386
```

but this gives me the error:

```
dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching libhdf5-serial-dev_1.8.4-patch1-3ubuntu2_i386
```

I was hoping someone could explain the origin of the initial error and suggest a fix.

Answer (score 6):

Open your terminal( <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and paste as

```
 sudo dpkg --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libhdf5-serial-dev_1.8.4-patch1-3ubuntu2_i386.deb
```

Comment: `-i` is missing

Answer (score 2):

> trying to overwrite '/usr/include/hdf5.h', which is also in package **hdf5** 1.8.12-2

The name of the package is `hdf5`. You remove it and everything will be dandy again:

```
 sudo dpkg -r hdf5
```

Continue.