# Fix broken install error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe) (NOT DUPLICATE)

Tags: dpkg

I tried to fix a broken install:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies...Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
 Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bridge-utils docker-ce-rootless-extras gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0 gyp ipset libc-ares2 libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libgraphite2-dev libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libicu-le-hb-dev libicu-le-hb0
  libicu60:i386 libiculx60 libipset3 libjs-async libjs-inherits libjs-node-uuid libjuh-java libjurt-java libneon27-gnutls libridl-java libssl1.0-dev libstartup-notification0 libunoil-java libuv1-dev
  linux-headers-5.0.0-37 linux-headers-5.0.0-37-generic linux-image-5.0.0-37-generic linux-image-5.3.0-40-generic linux-modules-5.0.0-37-generic linux-modules-5.3.0-40-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-37-generic linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-40-generic node-abbrev node-ansi node-ansi-color-table node-archy node-async node-balanced-match node-block-stream node-brace-expansion
  node-builtin-modules node-combined-stream node-concat-map node-cookie-jar node-delayed-stream node-forever-agent node-form-data node-fs.realpath node-fstream node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git
  node-glob node-graceful-fs node-gyp node-hosted-git-info node-inflight node-inherits node-ini node-is-builtin-module node-isexe node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile node-lru-cache node-mime node-minimatch
  node-mkdirp node-mute-stream node-node-uuid node-nopt node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once node-osenv node-path-is-absolute node-pseudomap node-qs node-read node-read-package-json node-request
  node-retry node-rimraf node-semver node-sha node-slide node-spdx-correct node-spdx-expression-parse node-spdx-license-ids node-tar node-tunnel-agent node-underscore node-validate-npm-package-license
  node-which node-wrappy node-yallist nodejs-doc php7.2-bcmath php7.2-zip pigz ubuntu-fan
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  emacs25-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  emacs25-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 182 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/17.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 70.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 547418 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../emacs25-common_25.3~2.gitc09215a-kk1+18.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking emacs25-common (25.3~2.gitc09215a-kk1+18.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs25-common_25.3~2.gitc09215a-kk1+18.04_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/subdirs.el', which is also in package emacs26-common 26.3~1.git96dd019-kk1+18.04
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs25-common_25.3~2.gitc09215a-kk1+18.04_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Using the suggested solutions from [subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383079/subprocess-paste-was-killed-by-signal-broken-pipe)

But the solution does not work due to dependencies:

```
$ sudo dpkg -r emacs26-common
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of emacs26-common:
 emacs26 depends on emacs26-common.

dpkg: error processing package emacs26-common (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 emacs26-common
```

Comment: No, it's a duplicate. A fairly common duplicate. Look for the `(broken pipe)` line and the three lines above it: Package A and Package B are both trying to provide File X. That means Packages A and B *conflict*. You cannot have both installed simultaneously without forcing. Pick the package you want (A or B), and uninstall the other.

Comment: You can't have both `emcas26` and `emacs25` installed at the same time. If you want `emacs25`, then uninstall all the packages related to `emacs26`

Comment: @user535733 thank you

Comment: What OS & release are you on?   I see packages that are EOL & from unsupported release(s)